# How to re-direct standard output as it comes from Stream

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am trying to re-direct standard output from a Process, but I want to re-direct line by line as the other process outputs rather than all at once. Right now my code looks like this:

```
proc->StartInfo->FileName = "ping.exe";
proc->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
proc->StartInfo->RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc->StartInfo->Arguments = "-n 1 www.google.com";
proc->Start();

StreamReader^ stream = proc->StandardOutput;


if(stream){
    //String^ s = stream->ReadToEnd();
    //Console::WriteLine(s);
    proc->WaitForExit();
    while(stream->Peek() >= 0)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(stream->ReadLine());
    }

}
```

But what it has to do is wait for the process to exit before printing all of the Ping output. If you run ping natively, you can see that the output comes periodically as the HTTP requests are made. I basically want the output to be queued up and re-directed the same way, line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
String^ s;
        //Console::WriteLine(s);
        //proc->WaitForExit();
        while(s=stream->ReadLine())
        {
            Console::WriteLine(s);
        }
```

This works